# Problem in calculating the global sections of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d)\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, toric-varieties, blow-ups

This is an additional question to the one I posed in [Equivalence of sequences of blowups of $\mathbb{P}^3$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408362/equivalence-of-sequences-of-blowups-of-mathbbp3)

Let $[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ be coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $Z\subset \mathbb{P}^3$ the subscheme given by the ideal $$I_Z=(x_1,x_2,x_3^2) \subset \mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$$ i.e. $Z$ is a double point supported on the line $L:(x_1=x_2=0)$.

I want to prove that $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d)\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z)=h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d))-2$, with $2=length(Z)$.
In order to do this I first blow up the proper base locus in $\mathbb{P}^3$, i.e. the point $p=[0,0,0,1]$, and then blowup the point $q$ corresponding to the direction of the line $L$ in $E_p$ where $E_p \subset Bl_{p}\mathbb{P}^3$ is the exceptional divisor of the first blowup.
Let us finally denote with $E_q\subset Bl_{q}Bl_{p}\mathbb{P}^3$ the exceptional divisor of the second blowup and $E_p'$ the strict transform of $E_p$.
In this way the strict transform of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d)\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z$ corresponds to divisors in $Bl_{q}Bl_{p}\mathbb{P}^3$ of the form $dH-E_q-E_p'$, with $H$ the strict transform of the hyperplane section of $\mathbb{P}^3$.
First I consider the exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow dH-E_p' \rightarrow dH \rightarrow dH_{|E_p'}\rightarrow 0$$ and since the restriction is the trivial bundle we have $h^0(dH_{|E_p'})=1$ yielding $h^0(dH-E_{p}')=h^0(dH)-1$.

Next I consider the following $$0 \rightarrow dH-E_p'-E_q \rightarrow dH-E_{p}' \rightarrow (dH-E_{p}')_{|E_q}\rightarrow 0$$
At this point I have that still $dH_{|E_q}$ is trivial but ${E_{p}'}_{|E_q}$ is the class of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1)$ being $E_q \cong \mathbb{P}^2$ and $E_p' \cap E_q=l$ the exceptional line in $E_p' \cong Bl_q\mathbb{P}^2$.

But now the dimensions do not match, since $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(1))=3$ not giving me the right answer $h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d)\otimes \mathcal{I}_Z)=h^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d))-2$

Do anyone know what am I missing?
Thanks in advance for eventual answers or remarks.

Comment: I suppose that you are aware that it is essentially trivial to prove that the restriction map $H^0(\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(d))\rightarrow H^0(\mathscr{O}_Z)$ is surjective. Do you have some reason to do it in this complicated way?

Comment: @abx Yes the direct way it works much easier. My doubt was why this complicated way (that seems right to me) do not give the same answer as the easy one